# Laravel $request file

Tags: file, laravel, post

$request file return me exception-"Call to a member function move() on null"

```
<form  action="{{url('/addnews')}}" class="reviews-form" role="form" 
<input type="file" name="file">
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

in Controller:

```
public function AddData(Request $request)
{
$file=$request->file('file');
$file->move('images',$file->getClientOrginalName());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. define method: POST, You cannot send file using GET method (without exact definition it acts as GET
2. define enctype param to inform web server that You're sending file

Fix the form:

```
<form  action="{{url('/addnews')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="reviews-form" role="form">
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I hope You've defined in router file that POST **/addnews** refers to Your controllers **addData** action.

I recommend to use named routes to make Your code more accurate, make it to be as convention.

change name of action from addData => create,

and make Your routes.php file have something like this:

```
Route::post('/news', ['as' => 'news.add', 'uses' => 'NewsController@create']);
```

Form:

```
<form  action="{{route('news.add')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="reviews-form" role="form">
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Big +1 for the POST, I missed that.

Answer (score 5):

Your `<form>` tag needs `enctype="multipart/form-data"` (as well as `method="post"`). Without the enctype, no file data will be included with the request, leading `$request->file('file')` to be null.

You should also check `$request->file('file')` is a file before attempting to move it (Laravel's Validation class has a `file` rule specifically for this). Some of your users will certainly neglect to upload a file and should receive a helpful validation error instead of an exception.